# Low latency logging of timestamps that are usually nanoseconds apart

Tags: java

I am trying to check the overhead due to a particular method in Java. 
Say the method is "Send(Message)", I want to "log(timestamp); Send(Message); log(timestamp)", and find the difference between the timestamps. The catch is that the method is very fast (the expected difference is in nanoseconds). I don't want to also measure the time taken to log the timestamp (unless it is very negligible). Could you please recommend a way to log the timestamps efficiently?

Comment: Also, you may want to have a look at [caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way of doing this is to log the time before the method call then call the method thousands or even millions of times and log the end time. A quick division will tell you to total time for a single call (which will be very small).

Due to JIT'ing make sure you test the method in the same way it will run in production or you could end up with a different result in the real world to one in testing. Additionally you might like to run the method a few thousand times before starting the time test to try to ensure you are actually running the fully optimized code.

Comment: Thanks a lot wobblycogs and fge!

Answer (score 0):

If you are afraid of the `log` overhead, the workaround is simple:

```
final long before, after;

before = System.nanoTime();
send(message);
after = System.nanoTime();

log("before: " + before);
log("after: " + after);
```

The only overhead left is therefore the call to System.nanoTime().